# Buck Converter has minimum output current

Tags: buck

I was looking online for a buck converter and I came across this on eBay:

https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/DC-DC-5-40V-to-3-3V-5V-9V-12V-24V-Buck-Step-Down-Converter-Volt-Linear-Regulator/263325140035?hash=item3d4f66c443:g:hwgAAOSwJyhdg0ay

[image]

[image]

What does it mean by a 1.5A minimum output current? Can it not handle a no-load condition?

Comment: This is not uncommon for switching supplies.   They need a minimum output current to maintain their output.   With no load, the output generally will rise

Comment: I agree with @KyleB but this is probably the minimum guaranteed output current.  A true minimum current should be many orders of magnitude lower than max rated.

Comment: @winny Yeah I thought of that too, and it did seem the order of magnitude is off.   But it'd also be odd if 1.5 is a guaranteed min but 2.2 is typical...thats also a bit weird.   I wonder...possible thats a typo and it should say 1.5mA, not 1.5A.    Thats an eBay listing, always take with a grain of salt!

Comment: Or that you can get 1.5A at the maximum input-output voltage differential, and 2.2A when its less????

Comment: @KyleB Could be. Don’t expect much from eBay items.

Comment: "**Buck** step down converter (redundant) volt(?) **linear regulator**". "Characteristic frequency 100 MHz". WTF seems most appropriate.

Comment: As @DavidMolony has said in his answer, this is not a buck converter. It's funny to see a minimum load current of 1.5A with an input-output voltage difference of 40V. If you apply 12V input and adjust the output to 5V, you'll fry the device when you try to draw that "minimum" load current.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen with not just one but TWO temperature ratings. One of which his military grade. Don't buy this garbage from that piece of trash liar.

Comment: @DKNguyen Yes, I stopped reading the rest, it's rare that I see snake oil so badly labelled. It's almost as if it's daring the buyer.

Comment: Thank you for the responses! I shall find a better part!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. this is not a Buck converter... There's no inductor so it can't be. Linear reg.
2. the 1.5A isn't a minimum current draw, it's a repeat of the max current capability.
3. This is not a good part. Find a different one, it will generate a lot of heat. The abundant errors in the listing just say no. Don't buy it.

Comment: There are many clues that it's a linear regulator with LM317. Best clue is the picture where it reads LM317 on the chip. Indeed, that's no buck converter.

Answer (score 0):

This seller has succeeded if he wants to rise some high hopes and sell something totally different without writing a single lie.

You have already generated in your head a hope of an excellent low cost wide range buck converter. If you buy it and try to get your money back you will not get anything because you have built the idea of buck converter in your imagination. The seller will say "I sold a linear regulator which is an excellent post regulator for a buck regulator when the ripple must be reduced and the output current is no more than 1.5 amperes".

Comment: While this does sound like a good excuse, I honestly somehow doubt that was the intent, but I can't quite put my finger on it. Probably because there are so many things that I could touch in one go.